# Is there a way to see all VSCode windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find it more practical to open several github pages (using github1s.com) because I can quickly switch between projects via the tabs of my browser.

If I open multiple projects in vscode, then I have to deal with multiple windows of the same software, which is not well-supported in MacOS.

Maybe there's a way to display tabs for each opened projects in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Hold Command + ` (tilde key, to the left of 1 on your keyboard) to switch between windows of the same app.